# Lie Algebra representations outside of generalized central characters

Tags: rt.representation-theory, d-modules, geometric-representation-theory

For a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we can view its category of representations as fibered over $\operatorname{Spec}Z(\mathfrak{g})$ (a representation will lie over a point if the center's action factors through the corresponding ideal). If we restrict to category $\mathcal{O}$, then every object will be a direct sum over objects laying over a formal neighborhood of a closed point — the center acts through a "generalized central character". I'm trying to understand what happens if we consider all representations. Beilinson–Bernstein's localization gives an equivalence between twisted $D$ modules on the flag variety and representations on which the center acts by a generalized character $$\mathfrak{g}\operatorname{-mod}_{\varpi(\lambda)} \simeq D _{\lambda}\operatorname{-mod}(G/B)$$ for any regular dominant weight ($\varpi$ is the quotient by the action of the Weyl group).

1. Is there a geometric description of non regular weights?
2. What can be said about fibers over subschemes of positive dimension (i.e. the center action factors through an ideal corresponding to a subvariety of positive dimension)? Are there any indecomposable objects belonging to those fibers?
3. Is there a description of $\pi_*D(G)$ in terms of localization ($\pi : G \to G/B$)?